# Foreach and $_SESSION doesn't work

Tags: php, session, foreach

I have a function for creating new sessions:

```
public function Create($data = array())
{
    foreach($data as $name => $value)
    {
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;;
    }
}
```

and I'm using the following example:

```
Session::Create([
    '_USER_ID' => $fetch_id,
    '_USER_IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    '_USER_AGENT' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    '_USER_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],
    '_USER_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_ACCEPT_ENCODING']
]);
```

This create only ONE Session "_USER_ID", other sessions don't exist.
Where is problem?

```
var_dump: array(1) {["_USER_ID"]=> int(1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` after the end of foreach (FYI : `return` break the loop) :

```
public function Create($data = array())
{
    foreach($data as $name => $value)
    {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;;
    }

    return $_SESSION;
}
```